# Should I mention Canadian PR status in my CV?

Tags: resume, cover-letter, canada

I hold a Canadian PR (permanent resident) but I'm currently working outside of Canada. Do I need to mention my PR status in the CV, as I'm not sure recruiters read cover letters.

I've applied for a few jobs which match my experience (finance/consulting) very well but didn't even get an interview call. This makes me wonder if my Canadian PR status was overlooked.

I know similar questions have been asked before but this is a Canada-specific query. Thanks.

Comment: Very similar to [How do I indicate I'm not a foreign national on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12668)

Comment: *working outside* Of what?

Comment: "outside of Canada" -- edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think recruiters don't read cover letters?

Comment: @user1451111 A few of my job applications were rejected despite my profile being a good fit (in my opinion). I felt that they would've at least given me a look-in unless they thought I was not allowed to work in Canada (by not reading the cover letter). Of course they could've seen my PR status but still decided against progressing my case because they wanted someone local or someone who could join at short notice. I'll never know. But it does make sense to put this detail in my CV just to be doubly sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, of course you should (when applying for jobs in Canada).

This is a pertinent fact and increases your chances of being interviewed and offered the job.

For instance, I mention that I am security cleared when applying for defence work, as it can take a few months to obtain clearance. If I didn't, I am sure that potential employers might skip past me to someone who does mention it, as it saves them a lot of paperwork and a delay of several months before i can join the project.

Similarly, I used to add that I was Singapore PR when applying there (be aware that PR status can lapse if you leave the country for a while)